# STM32 change PWM Duty Cycle dynamically in RTOS

Tags: stm32, freertos, rtos, pwm, cmsis

I'm using this code below trying to achieve a intensity transition effect upon turning on a light:

```
void output2ControlTask(void *argument)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN output2ControlTask */
  uint32_t DutyCycle = 0;
  /* Infinite loop */
  for(;;)
  {
    if(flag_EN_OUTPUT2 == ON){
      SteadyBurn_PWM_RTOS(&htim2, TIM_CHANNEL_3, DutyCycle);
      if(DutyCycle < 100){
        DutyCycle++;
      }
    }
    if(flag_EN_OUTPUT2 == OFF){
      SteadyBurn_PWM_RTOS(&htim2, TIM_CHANNEL_3, DutyCycle);
      if(DutyCycle > 0){
        DutyCycle--;
      }
    }
    osDelay(100);
  }
  /* USER CODE END output2ControlTask */
}
```

```
void SteadyBurn_PWM_RTOS(TIM_HandleTypeDef *htim, uint32_t Channel, uint32_t intensity_percentage){
    __HAL_TIM_SET_COMPARE(htim, Channel, (uint32_t)(COUNTER_PERIOD * (float)(intensity_percentage/100)));
}
```

Somehow when observed with an oscilloscope the output delayed for like 10 seconds (make sense with `osDelay(100)`) and then outputted a 100% Duty Cycle PWM, with no transition effect.

I remember using this code without in RTOS environment works fine. I thought about priority issues but when I changed `DutyCycle` to any `int` and left out the `DutyCycle` it outputs the corresponding PWM instantly.

I also debugged the `DutyCycle` and it was in the correct increment in runtime as well.
Is it a HAL problem?

Comment: What does "changed DutyCycle to any int and left out the DutyCycle" mean?

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to change the `DutyCycle` variable first, then call `SteadyBurn_PWM_RTOS()`? You do it backwards - you set the current duty cycle, modify the variable, then delay.

Comment: @pmacfarlane `SteadyBurn_PWM_RTOS(&htim2, TIM_CHANNEL_3, 100);` will work. without `DutyCycle` variable involved. I mean do it backwards make sense, but still the HAL function won't take it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right, it was a casting problem afterall.

removed a pair of parentheses on the math function and it works.

```
__HAL_TIM_SET_COMPARE(htim, Channel, (uint32_t)(COUNTER_PERIOD * (float)intensity_percentage/100));
```